# Multiplication of complex numbers in python

Tags: python, math, computer-science, complex-numbers

I am trying to simulate the propagation and reflectance of a light spectrum in multiple layers of materials through a method called "transfer matrices", however when trying to calculate the propagation matrices P1 and P2 the matrices simply do not give what what they should give What I suspect is that it is a problem when operating with the complex number defined by j (`np.exp(-1j*p1)`). Could someone who has worked with complexes in python help me identify the problem?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

Lambda_Cero = 1500*10**(-9) # resonance wavelenght
nH = 2.32  # Material high refractive index
nL = 1.38  # Material low refractive index
na = 1     # air refractive index
nb = 1.5  # Substrate refractive indes
N = 5 # Numbers of layers

m = 0
r= []
l1 = []
for i in np.arange(250*10**(-9), 2000*10**(-9), 1*10**(-9)):

  r.append([])
  l1.append([])
  
  k1 = (2*np.pi*nL)/i
  d1 = Lambda_Cero/(4*nL)
  p1 = k1*d1

  k2 = (2*np.pi*nH)/i
  d2 = Lambda_Cero/(4*nH)
  p2 = k2*d2

  A1 = (nH+nL)/(2*nH)
  A2 = (nH-nL)/(2*nH)
  A3 = (nH+nL)/(2*nL)
  A4 = (nL-nH)/(2*nL)


  DLH = np.array([[A1, A2],[A2, A1]])
  DHL = np.array([[A3, A4],[A4, A3]])
  ##### Propagation P1 and P2                              

  P1 = np.array([[np.exp(1j*p1), 0], [0, np.exp(-1j*p1)]])
  P2 = np.array([[np.exp(1j*p2), 0], [0, np.exp(-1j*p2)]])
  


  M = DHL*P1*DLH*P2
  M_N = M**5

  #GaN y SiO2
  k1 = (2*np.pi*nL)/i
  d1 = Lambda_Cero/(4*nL)
  p1 = k1*d1
  A3 = (nL+nb)/(2*nb)
  A4 = (nL-nb)/(2*nb)
  DbL = np.array([[A3, A4],[A4, A3]])

  ##### Propagation P1
  P1 = np.array([[np.exp(p1*1j), 0], [0, np.exp(-p1*1j)]])

  #Ta2O5 and air

  A3 = (nH+na)/(2*na)
  A4 = (nH-na)/(2*na)
  DHa = np.array([[A3, A4],[A4, A3]])
  Mf = DHa*M_N*DbL*P1
  
  r[m].append(abs(Mf[1,0]/Mf[0,0]))
  #r[m] = abs(Mf[2,1]/Mf[1,1])
  l1[m].append(i)
  m = m+1

print(M_N   )
plt.plot(l1, r, "-ob")
plt.title("Interpolación lineal")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

This is the equation for the propagation:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what is going wrong in your code? What do you expect and what are you getting instead? How do you know what to expect? Are you confident your `p1` and `p2` values (that you're multiplying by `1j` and `-1j` to make your matricies) are correct? If you're seeing very small errors (e.g. a value you expect to be real has a tiny imaginary component), you might just be having floating point accuracy issues.

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question.  But 250*10**(-9) and the other numbers like that should be written in scientific notation as 250E-9.  You'll get slightly better accuracy.